# Cycles in cycles using javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, setinterval

I want to create a periodic process with inner cycles, using javascript. Each cycle is represented by consequently changing circles - with specified time interval between them and specified time interval between cycles. The problem is also getting harder, because I also need a variable time interval between cycles and circle (which I'm going to do using random number function).

Currently I have the following code, which doesn't work properly:

```
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="canv" widht="800" height="500"></canvas>
<script>

var ctx=document.getElementById("canv").getContext('2d');
var cnt=0;

var int0=self.setInterval(function(){startDraw()},5000);

function startDraw ()
{
    var int1=self.setInterval(function(){DrawC()},1000);
    cnt++;
    if (cnt==3)
    {
        int0=window.clearInterval(int0);
    }
}

function DrawC()
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(200, 200, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();  
    var int2=self.setInterval(function(){DrawGC()},1000);
    int1=window.clearInterval(int1);
}

function DrawGC() 
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(200, 200, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fillStyle="green";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();  
    var int3=self.setInterval(function(){DrawWC()},1000);
    int2=window.clearInterval(int2);
}

function DrawWC() 
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(200, 200, 52, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();  
    int3=window.clearInterval(int3);
}

  function getRandomInt(min, max)
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

</script>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the timer variables as global. Try:

```
var int0, int1, int2, int3;
```

Remove these variable declarations from the functions.

Try out this code, is this what you need?

```
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="canv" widht="800" height="500"></canvas>
<script>

var ctx=document.getElementById("canv").getContext('2d');
var cnt=0;

var int0, int1, int2, int3;

circleTime = 1000;
cycleTime = 5000;


int0 = self.setInterval(startDraw, cycleTime);

function startDraw ()
{
    console.log("startDraw...");
    // Start drawing circles
    self.setTimeout(DrawC, circleTime);

    cnt++;
    if (cnt == 4)
    {
        // Stop startDraw
        int0 = window.clearInterval(int0);

        /*
        // Let's draw again
        cnt = 0;
        cycleTime = getRandomInt(5000, 10000);
        circleTime = getRandomInt(1000, 2000);
        int0 = self.setInterval(startDraw, cycleTime);
        */
    }
}

function DrawC()
{
    console.log("Circle...");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(200, 200, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();  

    self.setTimeout(DrawGC, circleTime);
}

function DrawGC() 
{
    console.log("greenCircle...");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(200, 200, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fillStyle="green";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();  

    self.setTimeout(DrawWC, circleTime);
}

function DrawWC() 
{
    console.log("whiteCircle...");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(200, 200, 52, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();  
}

function getRandomInt(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

</script>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll going to make the number of cycles to be taken from the textbox, but, anyway, let it be 4 cycles in the example.

Comment: Great! Anyway, the random cycle interval didn't work, but I uncommented strings "        cycleTime = getRandomInt(5000, 10000);
        circleTime = getRandomInt(1000, 2000);" and it works fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should change the first `cycleTime = 5000;` to `cycleTime = getRandomInt(5000, 10000);`.

Answer (score 0):

problem 1 with this code:
 you are using int2 (defined in DrawC) as if it was defined globaly, the interval will not be cleared because int2 has no value in DrawGC.
 try defining them global 
 `var int1, int2, int3`; as first line in your code

secondly, why are you using intervals if you want to cancel them after 1 loop, use `setTimeout()` instead which only calls the method once

Comment: setTimeout is not the solution, becaus, as I understand, while JS processing time-out is set accordingly to current time, so, set Timeout will not work properly in cycles (instead of seconds interval between cycles I'll get milliseconds interval).